# How to search for not matched string in C#

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var students = new List<Student>() {
            new Student(){ Id = 1, Name="Bill"},
            new Student(){ Id = 2, Name="Steve"},
            new Student(){ Id = 3, Name="Ram"},
            new Student(){ Id = 4, Name="Abdul"}
        };

        String name = "Ram Mohan";
        foreach (var result in students)
        {
            if (!result.Name.Equals(name))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name not exsists");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here name "Name not exsists "was printing for 4 times, i understood why it was printing for 4 times
but i want to print "Name not exsists only once", it should check in the entire list
if the string not contains in the list
then it should print "Name not exsists" only once

Comment: `var noneMatch = students.All(s => s.Name != name)`. Or keep a bool which you modify when a result was found, breaking out of the loop if so.

Comment: You may be looking for a simple [boolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/bool) or a way to [break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break) out of the loop if you find the name?

Comment: i want to come out of the loop if name finds else it should print the message  "Name not exsists"

Comment: Then invert your condition and break.

Comment: How do you want to match names? Exact match? Or "startswith" ?

Comment: I want exact match

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gZnMPb, You do realize, that your example does not match exactly, right? Your concern is the output, right now, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Hey i hope that is the best solution @Fildor

Answer (score 0):

You can save a Boolean variable that will tell you if the name is in the list or not. If he is not in the list then the message: "Name not exists" will be shown. You can also add a break so when you find the name the loop will be over.

```
String name = "Ram Mohan";
bool IsNameInList = false;
    foreach (var result in students)
    {
        if (result.Name.Equals(name))
        {
            IsNameInList = true;
            break;
        }
    }

if(IsNameInList == false)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Name not exists");
}
```

Comment: So if the first doesn't match, you do not check the rest?

Comment: Will it search for entire list ?? After searching in whole entire list if it not finds then only it need to print "Name not exists" message

Comment: There are 2 issues here: Although it can be done simpler, this basically has the right logic, now. But the `Equals` will _never_ resolve to `true`, still.

Comment: instead of equals can we check with .contains ??? or is there any alternate way.

Comment: Problem is: You are equating `Student` class to a `string`. That won't work. _At least_ you need to equate `result.Name` to `name` (both strings).

Comment: yeah  its my mistake i have changed the same in question now. the logic is okay for 4 records but if there is lot of data in list like around 40k will it check fast ?

Comment: If you don't come up with another datastructure, then it will be O(n) ... But I'd care for performance, when it becomes a problem. 1. Make it, 2. Make it run, 3. Make it run correctly, 4. Make it run fast (if you need to)

Answer (score 0):

Use linq :)

```
var students = new List<Student>() {
    new Student(){ Id = 1, Name="Bill"},
    new Student(){ Id = 2, Name="Steve"},
    new Student(){ Id = 3, Name="Ram"},
    new Student(){ Id = 4, Name="Abdul"}
};
String name = "Ram Mohan";
if (!students.Any(e => e.Name.Equals(name))) {
    Console.WriteLine("Name not exsists");
}
```